# xampp phpmyadmin access denied error(#2002) on linux

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, endless-os

I installed xampp in my pc(Linux endless os 3). Php is working fine but when I open my http://localhost/phpmyadmin in the browser it is displaying an error

> 2002 - No such file or directory — The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).

Error is shown as below
[image]

Comment: write 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost

Comment: Please checkout [this article](https://www.linux.com/learn/intro-to-linux/2017/4/endless-os-unique-take-linux-thats-perfect-new-users) before go further with endless OS as a development machine OS

Answer (score 1):

Open the file `config.inc.php` in any text editor.

Find this line

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
```

And change it to

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost:3307';
```

I find this solution in this website http://throughthesql.blogspot.com/2017/05/configuring-phpmyadmin-to-connect-to.html

Comment: port number should be 3306 or 3307 ?

Comment: 3307 works for me but 3306 is MySQL default port number and my reference link provide 3308 port which did not work for me.